# Turn off book style margins for amsart document class

Tags: margins, document-classes

Is there some way to turn off the alternation of larger left/right margins ("book style margins") when using a document class that turns this on by default? I'm looking to do this in particular with the `amsart` documentclass.

Comment: Do you mean `\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}` perhaps?

Comment: `amsart` (and the other ams document classes) does *not* alternate different sized margins.  by definition, the body is centered horizontally on the page (a requirement for creating plates for the press).  if what you really mean is the alternation of running heads, then youi should use the option `[oneside]` as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default of some (or many) classes is `twoside`, i.e. changing the margins for `verso` and `recto` pages (alternating).

Most of those classes provide a `oneside` option too, which switches this feature off!

- `amsart`
- `article`
- `book`
- `memoir`

have `twoside` by default, whereas `report` is `oneside` by default.

---

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: please see my comment on the question re `amsart` margins.